# How to manage multiple download with Firebase and RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have a `RecyclerView` and `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` with items. Each item has reference to some files in `Firebase` storage. each item has download button. I use `storageReference.getFile(location)`  to download files from firebase storage.
When I click on download button and wait for the download to finish, the checked icon (green icon) is showing correctly at specific position.

My problem is when I download multiple items at same time (when I click on multiple items), the green icon is not displays at appropriate position on every item.

How can I manage multiple download on every item simultaneously so that the green icon can be shown at specific position when specific item download finished?

The code in `OnBindViewHolder` behind the download button.

```
holder.imgDocumentChecker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        holder.imgDocumentChecker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.txtProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Document item = getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        final File parent = fileHelper.parentFolderGenerator(item);
        counter = 0;
        if (item.getFirebaseStorageFiles() != null && !item.getFirebaseStorageFiles().isEmpty()) {
            if (parent.listFiles() == null) {
                final String[] files = item.getFirebaseStorageFiles().split("____");
                if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        String fileName = files[i].substring(files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                        String storageFileUrl = Constants.ROOT_FIREBASE_STORAGE_URL + item.getDocFolder() + File.separator + files[i];
                        if (!parent.exists()) {
                            parent.mkdirs();
                        }

                        File localFile = new File(parent, fileName);
                        StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(storageFileUrl);
                        storageReference.getFile(localFile)
                          .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                counter++;
                                int valeur = (100 / files.length) * counter;
                                holder.progressBar.setProgress(valeur);
                                holder.txtProgress.setText(valeur + "");
                                Log.d("progressvalues:",  "valeur:"+valeur+"|counter:"+counter+"|lengh:"+files.length);

                                if (counter == files.length) {
                                    holder.txtProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    holder.imgDocumentChecker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.imgDocumentChecker.setImageResource(R.drawable.done_ic);
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                holder.txtProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            } else {
                startDocumentContentActivity(item, getRef(position));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please help.

Comment: You shouldn't make requests in the adapter since this view can be recycled and virtually disposed. I would recommend you to have another class handle the request and notify the adapter of these changes when the response comes in.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @JoaquimLey . Even if I make a separate class to handle the request I need to call this class from `OnBindViewHolder` when click occur in every item. Can you please explain your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments this request shouldn't be done in the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, and should **definitely not** be made in the `onBindViewHolder`.

You should abstract this to a separate class, a `Presenter` or the framework's own `ViewModel`, that being said:

Once that request is made and the new data comes in, you should update your adapter's data `model` and notify of these changes.

Reporting a click (that would eventually trigger a request) should be done via an interface where you could have your `Adapter`:

```
public interface Listener {
  void onItemClicked(YourModelPojo item);
}
```

And your Activity/Fragment/Presenter however abstract you want to do would implement this Listener interface.

So your adapter's

```
holder.imgDocumentChecker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        // Update the UI the request is being made and report to listener
        listener.onItemClicked(data.get(getAdapterPosition()));
}
```

Then your adapter should also have an update item on the adapter's data and notify of this change. Since your model changed your `bindViewHolder` would update the UI correctly.

Of course, you have to implement these UI changes (data downloading/updated/etc.)

---

I've written some articles that you can rely on (with open source code):

- [Using Android's ViewModel - MVVM](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-now-with-100-more-mvvm-11629a630125)
- [Using a Presenter - Model View Presenter](https://android.jlelse.eu/avenging-android-mvp-23461aebe9b5)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will read your tutorials and follow your suggestions.

Comment: Good luck, hope you can find a nice solution