# How to implement click listener using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick, firebaseui

I have a item holder class and FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.
How to manage click listener from activity on items that populate recyclerview.

My holder

```
public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ImageView item1,item2;

    public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        item1= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item1);
        item2= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item2);
    }

    public void bindView(Item item) {
        //TO DO
    }
}
```

Inside my activity

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, ItemHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(final ItemHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Item item) {
                holder.bindView(item);
                //How to handle
                //holder.item1 click listener not in onBindViewHolder
                //holder.item2 how to handle click listener not in OnBindViewHolder
            }

            @Override
            public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new ItemHolder(getLayoutInflater().from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false));
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                //TO DO
            }
        };
```

I read some tutorials that suggest to use an interface. Can you please tell me how to do it? with some sample code or instructions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1 You can do it, directly in onBindViewHolder, anyway:

```
holder.item1.setImageDrawable(item.getItem1());
holder.item2.setImageDrawable(item.getItem2());
```

2 For clicking a item, you need `ClickListener.java` and `RecyclerTouchListener.java`, you can check this [blog](http://interludioconjordan.wordpress.com/2018/02/19/interludio-sqlite-android-studio-crud-producto/). And in your activity:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new ClickListener() {

    @Override
     public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        //For CLICK
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
    //For Long CLICK
    }

}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I did it in onBindViewHolder but as recommanded in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274265/how-to-manage-multiple-download-with-firebase-and-recyclerview/49283229#49283229 I should never put it in `onBindViewHolder` . So I need to move it from `onBindViewHolder` .

Comment: public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener

Comment: How to get item clicked and some extra data from the activity if I make the click event inside `ItemHolder` @KMI ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `bindView` method, it's as simple as doing all your standard View operations... so you'd do something like this:

```
item1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        // TODO you
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer but I need to get **item clicked** and some extra data from the activity inside bindView. How is that possible with your suggestion ? @supercilex .

Comment: For the item, you already have it since you're passing it into the `bindView` method. As for getting data from the activity, you could just pass that into the `bindView` method too. Or as an unglier solution, you could do this: `(MyActivity) itemView.getContext()`.