# how to add item OnClickListener in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to set an onClickListener on my recyclerview. I retrieve data from Firebase and am able to load the data in the recyclerview. When I set an onClickListener nothing happens. How can I solve this?
**myadapter.class**

```
public class my adapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model,myadapter.myviewholder>{

public myadapter(@NonNull  FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myadapter.myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull  model model)
{
    holder.name.setText(model.getName());
    Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(model.getImgurl()).into(holder.img);

}

@NonNull

@Override
public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerow,parent,false);
    return new myviewholder(view);
}

class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    ImageView img;
    TextView name;
    Uri tvurl;

    public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {

        super(itemView);
        img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        name =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Once you have a `view` (like in `onBindViewHolder`) you can call `setOnClickListener` on it, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325798/how-to-implement-click-listener-using-firebaserecycleradapter/49326782). Is that not working for you? If so, can you show what you tried, and what results you got?

Comment: Have you solved the issue regarding setting onClickListener?

Comment: Can you create exoplayer with m3u8 link play??